# How To Create Template Based Dynamic URL with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask route this like:

```py
@app.route('/product/<string:slug>')
def product(slug):
    # some codes...
    return render_template('product.html', product=product)
```

Different clients use the project (different websites, same infrastructure). And every customer wants the product URL to be different. Like;

asite.com/product-nike-shoe-323

bsite.com/nike-shoe

csite.com/product/nike-shoue

vs. vs

How do I set the URL structure to come from the database?

like:

```
url_config = "product-{product_name}-{product_id}"
```

or

```
url_config = "product-{product_id}"
```

Note: please without redirect.

Comment: You have to set your url as `product/{product_name}-{product_id}`. I don't understand what you are trying to do, please edit your question or explain in comments and provide more information.

Comment: I want dynamic url structure as I specified on url config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with Flask's routing system. The URL map is supposed to be defined at startup and not change after that.

However, if you have some specific path where you need the dynamic parts (e.g. `/product/WHATEVER`), then you can register a route for `/product/<slug>` and query the database within your view function.

---

That said, if you REALLY want URL rules in a DB, and do not mind connecting to your database during startup (usually that's ugly), then nothing stop you from querying the database at startup time and define the URL rules based on data from the DB. Quite ugly, but doable.

Example:

```py
with app.app_context():
    url_map = {u.endpoint: u.rule for u in URLRules.query}

@app.route(url_map['foo'])
def foo():
    ...
```

Of course doing so makes it harder to nicely structure your app unless you use `app.add_url_rule()` for all the endpoints in a single place instead of the `@app.route()` decorators.

Likewise with blueprints of course.

Comment: You can register routes after the server starts just fine; it’s not as if the OP is looking to generate new URL paths on the fly all the time. E.g. Flask-Smorest let’s you [define if and on what URL to serve the OpenAPI specification](https://flask-smorest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/openapi.html#serve-the-openapi-documentation); that’s a dynamic route! Another example [Flask-Security-Too form URLs](https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html#login-logout). Etc etc.

Comment: Bottom line: the Werkzeug URLMap infrastructure is not immutable; you can register new routes *at any point in time*. The challenge will be *removing* routes, you could simply update the existing view respond with a 404 if a route is now considered “dead”. But it sounds to me like the OP just wants to make the URL path _configurable at start-up time_ anyway.

Comment: Mutating the url map will break as soon as you have multiple processes/servers though...

Comment: That's a fair point; but you could check for updates in an appcontext_pushed handler in each process. Provided there is a shared context that defines the routes.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not 100% clear on what you refer to when you say “database” here. From context I infer you *may* be talking about the Flask [Config object](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Config). If that’s the case, you can simply register your view function right after [setting up the app configuration](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/config/). Just call [`app.add_url_rule()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule) to register the URL pattern from the configuration to point to your view function of choice.

If, however, you are talking about a SQL or NoSQL database and you have built a web UI to register routes, then don’t dispair. Flask routes can be registered with the app object **at any point**. There is no point in the Flask app lifecycle after which you can no longer register a route!

All that registering a route does, is create a mapping between a URL template and *endpoint name*, an opaque string. Most of the time, you also register a function to be called to handle the specific endpoint, and most of the time, Flask infers the endpoint name from the function. Once registered in the mapping any next incoming request can be routed to the function for the given endpoint.

So, Flask keeps two maps:

- from url route -> endpoint name: [`Flask.url_map`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Flask.url_map)
- from endpoint name -> function: [`Flask.view_functions`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Flask.view_functions)

That said, there is  API for *removing* or *changing* url registrations (other than restarting your server, of course). You can’t change the url route, the endpoint name for a given route or what endpoint maps to what function. The *intention* of the framework is that you register your routes early on when first starting your server, via code that runs directly when imported or when bound to the app (Blueprints and Flask extensions do the latter). The majority of Flask apps will create their Flask instance, register all their routes and extensions, then pass the instance to the WSGI server for request dispatch, and that’s it. But there is nothing in the implementation stopping you from registering more routes after this point.

If you want to register URL routes from database information, you have to take care of at least the following two things:

1. Register existing routes at start-up. Once you have a connection to your database established, retrieve the existing routes and register them.
2. If a new entry is added to the database, register a new route.

First of all: if I were to implement something like this I’d use **one view function**. You can always figure out what url rule was matched and what endpoint name this mapped to by looking at [`request.url_rule`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.url_rule) and [`request.endpoint`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.endpoint), respectively.

Next, I’d explicitly generate endpoint names for each url rule from the database. Use the primary key in the name; you want to be able to find the database row from the endpoint name and vice versa. How you do this is up to you; let’s assume you know how to do this, and you have two functions for this named `pk_from_endpoint()` and `endpoint_from_pk()`.

Your view function can then look like this:

```py
from flask import request

def product_request(**kwargs):
    key = pk_from_endpoint(request.endpoint)
    row = database_query(key)
    # … process request
```

You register a route for a given database row with:

```py
app.add_url_route(row.url_config, endpoint_from_pk(row.id), product_request)
```

As mentioned, you can’t *change* URL registrations. But, as long as changes to these URLs are infrequent you could always add *new* registrations and for any old entries use `abort(404)` to return a 404 Not Found response.